# Native code + Phonegap Building in website

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

Native code can be added using a plugin in Cordova/Phonegap.

But is it possible to build the app with the plugin via the Adobe Phonegap Build site?

Answer (score 2):

You can. You must contribute the plugin to the community and then you can use it.

This should help [Contributing Plugins](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/developer_contributing_plugins.md.html)

Comment: and you also must wait untill the plugin has been validated before you can use it. You can find here a list of already accepted plugins : https://build.phonegap.com/plugins